# How to know when batch job in Apex has finished in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, batch-processing, apex

I have run into a bit of an issue in my apex controller. I am looping through events between a start and end date (max amount of days to pull events from is a month), but this leads to potentially thousands of events. So I do a soql loop of events so it chunks them into 200 events, then I loop through each event in the 200 chunk to create custom event objects to return to my visual force page.

However, inside this second for loop, I need MORE for loops to do work in finding people invited and what not, so my runtime for this is unfortunately O(3n^3) however, the first two for loops generally act as one (get one chunk of 200, loop through them all, get next one, etc) so it is more O(3n^2), but when in a test org with 2777 events in one month, I ran into CPU governor limit.

I am wanting to throw this into a batch job, as I think that is the only way to handle these large amounts of events (I cannot reduce my for loops anymore).

I am wanting to have the lightning loading spinner run until batch job finishes. However... I am not sure how to communicate between the batch job finish() method and my javascript in my visualforce page. I will be calling a method in my controller with a remote action call and unhiding the spinner, then that method will initiate the batch job, then when batch job ends, spinner stops and page refreshes with data.

But yeah, I don't quite know how I can connect the finish() to my javascript to detect when the batch job has finished.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a VF page that you want to react to a batch job that could take an nth number of time.. If you want that page to to be updated I would recommend looking into Streaming API, which I'm not even sure would solve your situation...  Batch jobs are asynchronous obviously, so I don't think your requirements are realistic.  I guess the bigger question is what are you trying to solve for, and if your requirements is to build a dynamic page off a async job that isn't realistic

Comment: Largely the only issue is when a user wants to view a month worth of events, there can just be too many and the CPU time governor limit... I am not an expert in Apex so was wondering if this could possibly be a solution, but it seems like there just may not be one. We were thinking of just reducing events if they reach a limit and letting the user know they'll have to narrow their view date range to see some events

Comment: What is an event?  Like a standard object Activity?

Comment: Oh, it is working in Salesforce, so it is taking salesforce event objects and putting them into a scheduler client side

Comment: So in Salesforce there is Activities, Activities have Tasks and Events.   I don't understand what you trying to do

Comment: Yes, those events are sobjects that you can query, which I am then translating them over to a scheduler on the client side

Answer (score 0):

You can check a salesforce batch status by providing job ID.
Below is a REST example:
curl `https://instance.salesforce.com/services/async/39.0/job/jobId/batch/batchId -H "X-SFDC-Session: sessionId"`

Comment: Why don't you Retreive all events in javascript and then loop/combine them client side?

Comment: I do have to loop through them all client side, as I have to make special event objects, but loop through them all server side to set up custom event objects with the same api names that I need on the client side. And looping through them server side is necessary for all the relations and what not to the event and setting them up as invitees. But, this is called through a static remote method, which throws another wrench in things... So I can't properly obtain the status of the batch job that I executed through a remote static method, or would need to hang the program server side waiting